# standard html canvas size for larger as well as smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I am using imgAreaSelect.js for image cropping.

Suppose there is an image of a 'rectangle' shape in the middle of the picture. On larger screen (desktop) when I select the rectangle shape, imgAreaSelect gives me its width & height (say 250 x 150 ). While on a smaller screen (mobile phone) it gives me width & height (say 100 x 50).

I use canvas to draw the cropped image on. So far I have been using the width & height obtained during selection as the width & height of the canvas. This produces images whose dimensions are bigger for the bigger screen while smaller for the smaller screens.

Is it possible in any way to get an image of a standard dimension whether it's cropped from a larger or smaller screen? If yes then do explain with some codes if possible. Thanks

Comment: you need to calculate the ratio between the actual imagesize and the display size and use the ratio to get the width and height you selected in the image not the canvas

Comment: Thanks for the reply Philipp.By 'actual imagesize' & 'display size' do you mean the 'natural' & 'rendered' dimension of the image??

Comment: yes. that's what I meant